# Centering with tabularx and minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx, minipage

I'm still new to LaTeX, and I have a litle problem, I have a table with 3 columns and one row, the first and last column are equal, and the middle take all the space. But I want to center content of it.
When I use `\centering` I got the result in the image bellow.
Is there any solution?

```
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|m{3cm}|X|m{3cm}|}
        \hline

        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm]{ump.png}
        \end{minipage}

        &

        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            Université Mohamed Premier \\
            École Nationale de Commerce et de Gestion \\
            Oujda. \\
        \end{minipage}

        &

        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm]{ump.png}
        \end{minipage}

        \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image: Code]
[image: Results]

Thank you very much.

Comment: A quick fix: use `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth` for the middle minipage

Comment: you don't need any of the minipages, just remove them, nor (I suspect) do you want the `table` environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|m{3cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|m{3cm}|}

    \hline
         \includegraphics[scale=3.1]{2.png}      
         & \vspace*{-9mm}
         Université Mohamed Premier\newline
          Ecole Nationale de Commerce et de Gestion\newline
           Oujda. 
            &
          \vspace*{5mm}
          \includegraphics[scale=3.1]{2.png}


        \\ \hline

     \end{tabularx}

     \end{table}


     \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're missing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You do not need the inner minipage or the outer table environment. It is probably simpler not to use tabularx either.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|m{3cm}|X|m{3cm}|}
    \hline


        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}


    &


        \centering
        Université Mohamed Premier \\
        École Nationale de Commerce et de Gestion \\
        Oujda.

    &

        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

    \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\bigskip

But simpler you don't need a table at all

\bigskip


\noindent
\mbox{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-a}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[b]{c}
        Université Mohamed Premier \\
        École Nationale de Commerce et de Gestion \\
        Oujda.
\end{tabular}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-b}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear sir I am new to latex please let me know the use of \noindent, when i remove the \noindent the output is still the same @David Carlisle

Comment: oops I'm missing `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` so the accented characters work.

Comment: @BikiTeron  without `\noindent` the start of a paragraph (which is the first image here) is indented by `\parindent` (15pt in report class)

Comment: Sir can you please show with the figures so that i can make differentiate @David Carlisle,  thanking you in advance.

Comment: @BikiTeron really you shouldn't ask unconnected questions as comments under an answer, just try it yourself: remove the first `\noindent` in the code I posted and tex's log will tell you `Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 29--30` as the line will have been shifted 15pt to the right

Comment: I am so sorry for asking unconnected question , thanking you for your kind reply @David Carlisle

Answer (score 3):

Use a simple `tabular` for each cell. This way, you get the logos vertically centered automatically as well as the text in the middle. You will also need a `>{\centering}` before the middle column to make it horizontally centered.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\cell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|>{\centering}X|c|}
\hline
    \cell{\includegraphics[scale=3]{logo.png}}
     & 
     \cell{Université Mohamed Premier \\
     École Nationale de Commerce et de Gestion\\
     Oujda.} 
     &
     \cell{\includegraphics[scale=3]{logo.png}} \\ \hline
 \end{tabularx}
 \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRt]

Answer (score 3):

As I don't think this will have to float (looks like a header), I removed the table environment. Centring is obtained by redefining the `X` columntype and using the `valign` key from `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx, adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx, cellspace}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}%

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Sc|X|Sc|}
\noalign{\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{0pt}}
\hline
     \adjincludegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{ump.png}
    &
        \centering
        Université Mohammed Premier \\
        École Nationale de Commerce\\ et de Gestion \\
        Oujda.
    &
        \adjincludegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{ump.png}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]